# Component Used but NOT Declared while being inside a Package

Tags: vhdl, quartus

In my Quartus project I have created two package files. I am creating a file which wishes to use both of those. But when I try to compile the file it says that some components are used but NOT defined. When I check the package to see if they are there, i find them. But the compiler throws me that message. Why is this?

I have tried the following. C/P the file that contains the component which is not found into a new file, renamed the new file and added it into the package. 
Somehow this works. But I dont understand why.

Screenshot 1: The declaration of an item inside a package TWICE with different names.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlehI.jpg

Screenshot 2: The libraries at the begining of the file that causes the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPvGK.jpg

Screenshot 3: The line of code that causes the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqL57.jpg

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

PACKAGE PIPELINE IS 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

component I_F IS

    PORT(
            GLB_CLK: IN  STD_LOGIC;
            STALL  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            PC     : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
            MEMWORD: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
            PC_ADD : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)

        );

END component I_F;


-- ... More components below

END PACKAGE PIPELINE;
```

Now on the file that I wish to use this component.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

LIBRARY WORK;
USE WORK.PIPELINE.ALL;
USE WORK.TOOLBOX.ALL; -- Thats the second package file
ENTITY TEST  -- Just for this example
       PORT ( Aa : IN BIT; B : OUT BIT);
END TEST;

ARCHITECTURE PROBLEMATIC OF TEST IS
    SIGNAL CLK : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL PIPE_STALL_SIG : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL PC_IN_NEXT_PC : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL IF_OUT_IFWORD : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL IF_OUT_PC_VAL : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);

    BEGIN
    IF1: I_F -- <== PROBLEM HERE                                    
         PORT MAP(  
                    GLB_CLK => CLK, 
                    STALL   => PIPE_STALL_SIG, 
                    PC      => PC_IN_NEXT_PC, 
                    MEMWORD => IF_OUT_IFWORD, 
                    PC_ADD  => IF_OUT_PC_VAL 
                 ); 
END PROBLEMATIC;

-- When i use A, the probblem appears, when I C/P A into a new vhd file, define 
-- it inside the package as shown above and then using the copy to the file that causes the trouble everything works..
```

**After changing the components name from I_F to ASDF for example, the problem was also solved**

Comment: Did you import the package?  

`library work;`

`use work.myPackage.all;`

Comment: Yes everything is in there.

Comment: We need a [MCVE].

Comment: I added the screenshots and the example...

Comment: Your code isn't quite a [mcve]. `ENTITY TEST` should be followed by the reserved word `IS`. The package `TOOLBOX` isn't provided (and the use clause can be commented out, also the library clause for `WORK` is redundant). Making the indicated changes allows the code to be analyzed and elaborated, while reporting I_F is not bound (lacking an entity declaration along with an architecture). The pictures are not useful. Provide actual error messages with the (fixed) MCVe (which may need to be elaborated to reproduce your actual problem).

Comment: Fyi it was a Quartus bug. Nothing wront with ma VHDL